# How to detect which (C++) language standard was selected in the Project->General Properties->C++ Language Standard

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019, c++20

I'm developing with *Visual Studio 2019*, and would like to be able to compile my C++ program conditionally based on the language standard chosen (*C++20, C++17, etc.*) from *Project Properties -> General Properties -> C++ Language Standard*.
What gets defined when I set it *C++20*, for example, so that I can use it as:

```
#ifdef WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE_FOR_C++_20 
#else
#ifdef WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE_FOR_C++_17
...
```

Comment: @jpo38 doesn't seem to work for conditional compilation.

Comment: Why? See my answer, it will definitely work for conditional compilation.

Comment: @jpo378 _HAS_CXX17 or _HAS_CXX20 seems to work, but are they standard?

Comment: Dunno, this may be only set by Visual Studio. `__cplusplus` proposed in my answer should work for all compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#if (__cplusplus >= 202002L)
    // C++20 (or later) code
#elif (__cplusplus == 201703L) 
    // C++17 code
#else
    // C++14 or older code
#endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.10.4
Thanks for your input

Comment: @Vectorizer That would then be a compliancy defect of Visual Studio, and a whooping big one at that.

Comment: @DevSolar: Maybe I am missing something.  All I am doing is setting the C++ language standard to C++17 and expecting the relevant portion of the code to be active.

Comment: @Vectorizer: Understood. Testing `__cplusplus` as shown here is a mechanism that is defined by the language standard, so every standard-compliant compiler should allow it. Unfortunately Microsoft thinks standards are for other people only. If it does not work as shown, that would be a fault in Microsoft's compiler, making it non-compliant in a pretty important way. Working around the issue by using some of Microsoft's non-standard extensions (as shown by ViralTaco_'s answer) makes your code less portable / readable, the *real* solution would be MS getting their act together.

Comment: @DevSolar Understood. I am afraid I don't have the means to influence Microsoft to get its act together. By the way, the problem is still here in the latest version: 16.11.7

Comment: @Vectorizer: What value does `__cplusplus` evaluate to in that version?

Comment: @DevSolar: Always to 199711 (for C++14, 17, 20)

Comment: @Vectorizer: [Set /Zc to enable updated __cplusplus macro.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-170). Sorry, didn't know about that myself.

Comment: @DevSolar: Thank you for your help on this while I was offline ;-)!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the MSVC [predefined macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170#microsoft-specific-predefined-macros) `_MSVC_LANG`:

```
#ifndef VT_CPP_VERSION
# if defined (_MSVC_LANG)
#  define VT_CPP_VERSION _MSVC_LANG
# else
#  define VT_CPP_VERSION __cplusplus
# endif
#endif

#if defined (VT_CPP_VERSION)
# if   (VT_CPP_VERSION >= 202002L)
  // 20 or above
# elif (VT_CPP_VERSION >= 201703L)
  // 17
# elif (VT_CPP_VERSION >= 201402L)
  // 14
# elif (VT_CPP_VERSION >= 201103L)
  // 11
# else
  // cry.
# endif
#endif
```

If you need to get this value after the code has already been compiled (for example: a shared library), then you can use a function.

```cpp
[[maybe_unused]] long version_used() noexcept {
#if defined (_MSVC_LANG)
  return _MSVC_LANG;
#else
  return __cplusplus;
#endif
}
```